# python re.search gives returns None even though substring is present in the string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to extract the position of assignment operators and conditional operators(and|or). I am very new to regular expression so please bear with me if the approach is wrong. I would also appreciate it if someone can provide a regular expression for the above statement as an example.

Right now I am parsing the string and the parentheses through a bunch of python functions to get the index and I have been successful at that. I wanted to give it a try using regex to see if it simplifies the solution.

```
test = "((condition one = 14) or ((condition two = 10) and (condition three = null)))"
re.search("(and$)", test).start()
m = re.search("and", test)
m.group()
```

Expected result - Index of the start position of 'and'

Actual result - NoneType Object has no attribute start

Comment: Why is there a `$` in your first pattern? That matches the end of a string.

Comment: You should use `re.search("and", test).start()` but why do you need regexes? You can simply use `test.index("and")`.

Comment: @Selcuk I am getting to know regex commands as I am using enumerate, a bunch of loops and functions to parse that string. The regex command is just to make sure I understand how to use it. Eventually, I may have to apply a regex for complex strings. It would be great if you can provide a regex to process the above string.

Comment: @rassar I assumed it signifies the end of a particular string. I am going through the documentation in detail now and noticed word boundary is \b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a regex like:

```
test = "((condition one = 14) or ((condition two = 10) and (condition three = null)))"
i = re.search("(and)|(or)", test).start()
print i
```

This prints out position of first `and` or `or` found:

```
22
```

Edit: To use `finditer` you will need to update above code a little:

```
test = "((condition one = 14) or ((condition two = 10) and (condition three = null)))"
pattern = re.compile(r"(and)|(or)")
for m in pattern.finditer(test):
    print(m.start())
```

outputs:

```
22
47
```

Comment: what if there are multiple instances? can I use the finditer method?

Comment: @Aditya I have updated my answer to use `finditer` method

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your regex, by just putting the word you are looking for.

```py
import re
test = "((condition one = 14) or ((condition two = 10) and (condition three = null)))"
i = re.search("and", test).start()
print(test[i:])
```

> and (condition three = null)))